# Should I doxygenate implementation files in a library of mine, in addition to the headers?

Tags: documentation, comments, implementations, headers

I'm in the process of writing Doxygen comments for this library of mine; it's a header-mostly C++ library, but it does have some code which gets linked rather than included.

For that code, which has .h/.hpp headers - should I also add Doxygen comments in the .cpp file, for the library to be "properly" documented, with the same level of commenting extensiveness as the headers? e.g. should I have file-level comments and detailed function-level comments on static  (file-scope) code?

PS - In case it's relevant (it probably isn't): [link to the actual library](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/) on GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

The general rules are that comments should be where you need them when maintaining the code and that the documentation should include what is relevant to the reader. Accordingly **all** your files should contain headers and function level comments but only the **public** methods normally need to be in the user documentation generated by Doxygen.d